# slideToggle() not animating on slideup or down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

I am working on a dropdown menu. The problem is that when the menu item is clicked and the menu should slide down, it opens late and doesn't animate. When it should slide up it also doesn't animate.

```js
$('.menu-vertical .nav-menu > li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('2000', 'swing');
});
```

```css
.menu-vertical .nav-menu li ul {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5 !important;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu-vertical">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>this is head
      <ul>
        <li>this is one</li>
        <li>this is one</li>
        <li>this is one</li>
        <li>this is one</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>head is head</li>
    <li>head is head</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: it works fine for me in chrome

Comment: The fiddle works fine for me as well. Is this just an excerpt from a larger code block? Is there a specific Browser + Version you are using as well?

Comment: use 2000 instead of '2000'

Comment: The fiddle works corretly for me - the first ul item is animating

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef it is not an issue i think

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Duration can be a string or number value, per the doc. http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: @JqueryKing We didnt know the real issue tell now .. but the '2000' in his code didnt make any effect .. I'm using chrome  and 2000 make effect for me but '2000' didnt

Comment: I've edited the OP's question to make it more clear what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @JqueryKing i am using also chrome 42.0.32 . but not working. :(

Comment: @Daved yes this is an excerpt from a large code block . but i have rewirtten it simply in fiddle but working same

Comment: @muhaimin there you go problem is solved use number instead of string.

Comment: @Daved it can be chrome bug . Even window.unload doesn't work in chrome .

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the problem may be a competing transition in your css.

Also the timing of the slide should be a number not a string. When passed as a string you're getting the default 400ms timing rather than the 2000ms timing you're trying to specify.

```js
$('.menu-vertical .nav-menu > li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(2000, 'swing'); // change '2000' to 2000
});
```

```css
.menu-vertical .nav-menu li ul {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5 !important;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  /*transition: all .4s ease; <- remove this bit*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="menu-vertical">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li>this is head
      <ul>
        <li>this is one</li>
        <li>this is one</li>
        <li>this is one</li>
        <li>this is one</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>head is head</li>
    <li>head is head</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I was just about to add a comment to Riteshk's answer about the transition. Interesting about the duration. jQuery Doc says it should accept String or Number, but you are correct that it's using default with String val supplied. Looks like a bug?

Comment: @Daved It will accept specified string values like "slow" or "fast"

Comment: Ah, touche. Always using an int, I forgot you can say "fast" or "slow". ;)

Comment: duration (default: 400)
Type: Number or String
A string or number determining how long the animation will run. From the Bible

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing the `$(document).ready()` event handler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //forgot this very important
  $('.menu-vertical .nav-menu > li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(2000, 'swing');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu-vertical .nav-menu li ul {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5 !important;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="menu-vertical">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
      <li>this is head
        <ul>
          <li>this is one</li>
          <li>this is one</li>
          <li>this is one</li>
          <li>this is one</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>head is head</li>
      <li>head is head</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't say that in the comment... make that your answer... otherwise people have to figure out what has changed in the code

Comment: Ah, good catch. The Fiddle is set to include in DomReady already. ;) Please edit your answer, though, so that it's clear what was added. It will make it easier for viewers.

Comment: @Daved added it to the answer

Comment: *its there in my code* - yes, but people would have to look for it... don't make people work, just tell them.  Give example if necessary, but don't expect people to read line by line a whole load of code to find the **one** change

Comment: @muhaimin the functionality you want works ,unless you are expecting something else

Comment: its as same as before

Comment: @apaul34208 If the JS executes in the head of the page without a .ready handler, it won't bind the click event to the LI element because it does not exist in the DOM yet. That's why the ready() handler is used. It has nothing to do with when the animation is triggered. It has to do with binding of the handler.

Comment: Here is the simpler version http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_slidetoggle

Comment: @apaul34208 Indeed, it's a good catch. However, that does not deal with the .ready() handler binding. In the case of the snippet added, it's working because the script executes after the elements are loaded in the DOM. If the JS is in the head of the page, it still needs a .ready().

Comment: @apaul34208 For clarification, these fiddles have the transition issue dealt with. This has no .ready with the code in the head: http://jsfiddle.net/w65pbw23/1/ and this one has the ready handler http://jsfiddle.net/w65pbw23/2/. ceteris paribus.

Comment: @Daved it appears that you are correct, sorry about that. Comments now deleted.

Comment: @apaul34208 I wouldn't delete the comments. It's not for argumentative purposes. I think it provides valuable knowledge on a topic that some people might not realize. Definitely no apologies necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```css
menu-vertical .nav-menu li ul {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5 !important;
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  transition: **background** .1s ease-in;
}
```

here is my change code for your solution in Only CSS code.

here in "transition" you have written "all" that contains all the element attached with this code will go for transition

**strong text**
as i know the first parameter in transition property is some css-property so you just need to only transits only those property you want

for more detail giving you reference link here for transition property below.

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/all_about_css_transitions.htm